# Looping through a class list with multiple items

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a class containing the following:

```
Public Class ConflictClass

    Public Sub New(ByVal emp As String, ByVal cli As String, ByVal serv As String, ByVal tme As String, ByVal dte As String, ByVal dy As String)
        _emp = emp
        _cli = cli
        _serv = serv
        _tme = tme
        _dte = dte
        _dy = dy
    End Sub

    Private Shared _emp As String
    Public Shared Property employee As String
        Get
            Return _emp
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _emp = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared _cli As String
    Public Shared Property client As String
        Get
            Return _cli
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _cli = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared _serv As String
    Public Shared Property service As String
        Get
            Return _serv
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _serv = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared _tme As String
    Public Shared Property appttime As String
        Get
            Return _tme
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _tme = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared _dte As String
    Public Shared Property apptdate As String
        Get
            Return _dte
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _dte = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared _dy As String
    Public Shared Property apptday As String
        Get
            Return _dy
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _dy = value.ToString.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

It is filled on one Windows form and I am trying to pass a list of this type to another form, loop through it (or use it as a data source) and fill a grid.  I am struggling to find an example of this.  Can someone help?

Comment: If you're passing it to another form, then the other form would have an entry point (`Function` or `Sub`) taking an argument `ByVal ... As List (Of ConflictClass)`.  The client code would make a new `List` and then call that entry point, passing the `List`.

Comment: Another option is to create a module that stores the list and reference the object in the module from both forms. Using a "global" has other downsides though, but it depends on your requirements.

Comment: ... or raise an event. The part of your code that generates the data can notify of a change other classes, which, when the event is raised, read (consume) the new data, updating what they have to update the moment it becomes necessary. The reference to the new data can be part of custom "EventArgs".